# tikz: Drawing a curve using the \foreach cycle

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

In [tikz: drawing a parametrised curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399425/tikz-drawing-a-parametrised-curve) I asked about drawing a curve using the `\pgfplotfunction` command.

I could make my code better if I could use the `\foreach` cycle:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm/2]
  \newcommand\rad{1}
  \pgfplothandlerlineto
  \foreach \phiparam in {0, 1, ..., 360}
           {
             \pgfpointxy{\rad *cos(\phiparam)}{\rad *sin(\phiparam)}
             \pgfusepath{stroke}
           }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to use the `\foreach` cycle to calculate parameters, plot points and connect them to show a smooth curve?

Comment: Do you want to draw a part of an cycle? Maybe helpful: [Draw arc in tikz when center of circle is specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66216/124842)

Comment: No! I really need a cycle because I would like to compute additional variables in its scope.

Comment: `\pgfusepath` can be executed once at the end and path can be added with `lineto`s.

Comment: @percusse Your comment is very valuable. Could you please provide a complete answer. I think one needs to use `\pgfpathmoveto` in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` can be part of a path.  You only have to unroll the 0-th iteration manually.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointxy{cos(0)}{sin(0)}}
  \foreach \phiparam in {1, ..., 360} {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointxy{cos(\phiparam)}{sin(\phiparam)}}
  }
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case `plot` might be just easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplothandlerlineto
  \pgfplotfunction{\x}{0,...,360}{\pgfpointxy{cos(\x)}{sin(\x)}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the approach I needed to circumvent. I am interested to write more complicated commands inside the scope of the cycle.

Comment: @Viesturs So you want to use the basic layer?  It's a bit unclear to me.  See updated answer.

Comment: The first part of your answer is what I was looking for - a bare `\foreach` cycle where additional commands can be inserted.